# Scroll on next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

Trying to scroll to next button on button click:

It works when you click on the title, but not when you click on 
Here is code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQyNyw

Anyone ideas?

Particular part that I'm having trouble with:

```
let activeIndex = 0; let scrollTopPadding = -100; let wrapper; let fields;


$(document).ready(() => {   wrapper = $('.wrapper');   fields = $('.field');    fields.click(function() {
    scrollToActiveField(this);   });
     let inputs = $('.field button');
     inputs.click(function(){
    scrollToActiveField($(this).parent());   });   inputs.click(function(event) { // enter
        let nextInputIndex = inputs.index(this) + 1;
        if (nextInputIndex < inputs.length) {
          inputs.eq(nextInputIndex).focus();
        }
         });
     setActiveTab(); });
```

Here is the working example https://codepen.io/benelliott/pen/beBPyJ - I need buttons instead of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from the the buttons in your form being an unknown type. I believe the form is defaulting them to a "submit" button which causes funny behavior (would love an additional answer/comment that explains this, I don't have the time right now to research it).

Easy fix though. Just add type="button" to each button and your codepen works: https://codepen.io/hyrumwhite/pen/WOQRzK

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form class="form" action="">
  <div class="field">
    <label>First name</label>
    <button type="button"> test</button> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <button type="button"> test</button> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Telephone</label>
    <button type="button"> test</button> 
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <button type="button"> test</button> 
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! One question though - seems like it doesn't work only on first click, would you know why?

Also, if you dont mind explaing why do we need to add type?

Comment: Actually it seems like it works when you click on the next button... But it doesnt scroll to the next one :( Here is the working example https://codepen.io/benelliott/pen/beBPyJ - I need instead of inputs buttons.